# Making a dictionary ... sort of

Tags: bash, shell

I have following set of values in a tab delimited file (only a part of values is shown here... file has 2 columns)

```
MXRA8   9.9074e-08
AURKAIP1    0.0000e+00
CCNL2   1.4962e-07
CCNL2   2.0536e-07
CCNL2   2.5198e-07
CCNL2   2.5311e-07
LOC148413   2.2558e-07
MRPL20  0.0000e+00
LOC441869   0.0000e+00
TMEM88B 0.0000e+00
```

As evident value for CCNL2 occur 4 times, what I want is that only the highest value for a repeated name in column one should be extracted and put into another file.

Something like this

```
MXRA8   9.9074e-08 
AURKAIP1    0.0000e+00 
CCNL2   2.5311e-07 
LOC148413   2.2558e-07 
MRPL20  0.0000e+00 
LOC441869   0.0000e+00 
TMEM88B 0.0000e+00
```

Any suggestions for a bash  Shell script script.

Or One liner in PERL

Comment: no simple shell script will interpret those float numbers you need python, perl..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { } { if (max[$1] == "" || $2 > max[$1]){ max[$1] = $2 } } END { for (var in max) { print var,"\t",max[var] } } ' tab-limited-data-file
```

That should print out the maximum for each value in the first column.

Comment: Thank's Arun. from which part of India?

Comment: Would be +1 except for useless use of `cat`.  Why not `awk ... file` (saves a pipeline) instead of `cat file | awk ... `?

Comment: @jw013: I also sometime write my answers using cat in front of sed/awk.  This shows that the input does not need to come from a file.

Answer (score 3):

Judging by sorts man-page, it handles floating point values with numeric-sort, but you might want to put this to the test:

```
sort --key=2 --general-numeric-sort --reverse input.txt | sort --key=1,1 --unique

AURKAIP1    0.0000e+00
CCNL2   2.5311e-07
LOC148413   2.2558e-07
LOC441869   0.0000e+00
MRPL20  0.0000e+00
MXRA8   9.9074e-08
TMEM88B 0.0000e+00
```

Comment: That's interesting. accepted answer without testing it. Well, it **doesn't** interpret floating point values, at least not here.

Comment: yeah, on more minor scrutiny I found it. :(

Comment: @jw013 - that is correct, I made a mistake when testing. `sort -g` sorts floating point numbers better than I do. :-)

Comment: Hmm, also curious. My sort (GNU version 8.5) explicitly says that its `-n` option does not sort leading `+` or exponential notation.  What version of sort do you have?

Comment: I have GNU sort v8.5. `-n` does not seem to handle `+x` expressions, whereas `-g` does. `echo -e "3.14e-2\n3.15e-5"|sort -g` vs `echo -e "3.14e-2\n3.15e-5"|sort -n` also illustrate the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You could sort first and then use awk to read the file line by line keeping only the max line.  If the repeated lines are always grouped as in the sample input, the sort can be avoided.

```
sort file | awk -F '\t' 'NR==1{last = $1; max = 0} {if (last != $1) {printf "%s\t%e\n", last, max; last = $1; max = $2} else if (max < $2) max = $2} END{printf "%s\t%e\n", last, max}'
```

Comment: what if I have 2 more columns of data and I want to do the same but based on value in column 4.